# Old version of Kile on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, versions, latex, kile

So far I have been using a previous version of Kile in Ubuntu 16. Upon installing Ubuntu 18.04, I found that the default version in apt packet manager is Kile 3.1 and even a beta version (that's what I get from `sudo apt-get install kile`). My question is, how is it possible to choose the version of kile that I want?

Comment: You could download the .deb package for 16.04, and install the requirements.